# XSLT Condition - If Details in Node A is true, display Details in Node B

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need help to put an XSLT condition that work:  within for-each loop that run through the question nodes; if condition on Node A works, display details in Node B.
Example of XML:

```
<Survey>
    <questions>
        <Number>1.0</Number>
        <Question>Was the show good?</Question>
        <Answer>Yes/No</Answer>
        <Details>N/A</Details>
    </questions>
    <questions>
        <Number>1.1</Number>
        <Question>Explain why</Question>
        <Answer>N/A</Answer>
        <Details>The actors were good</Details>
    </questions>
    <questions>
        <Number>2.0</Number>
        <Question>Was the food good?</Question>
        <Answer>Yes|No</Answer>
        <Details>N/A</Details>
    </questions>
    <questions>
        <Number>2.1</Number>
        <Question>Provide details</Question>
        <Answer>N/A</Answer>
        <Details>The pasta was too salty</Details>
    </questions>
</Survey>
```

What I need is to use the loop of for-each 
only If Question Number = 1.0 and Answer = 'Yes', display details in Question Number 1.1
only If Question Number = 2.0 and Answer = 'No', display details in Question Number 2.1

I have tried all the ways such as if, for each, choose/when, but it has not worked.
I have checked your other posts but could not find anything similar.  Thank you kindly, tubi.

I am sorry, so it should be like this:

```
    <Survey>     
        <questions>
            <Number>1.0</Number>
            <Question>Was the show good?</Question>
            <Answer>Yes</Answer>
            <Details>N/A</Details>     
    </questions>     
    <questions>
         <Number>1.1</Number>
         <Question>Explain why</Question>
         <Answer>N/A</Answer>         
         <Details>The actors were good</Details>
     </questions>     
     <questions>
         <Number>2.0</Number>
         <Question>Was the food good?</Question>         
         <Answer>Yes</Answer>
         <Details>N/A</Details>
     </questions>
     <questions>
         <Number>2.1</Number>
         <Question>Provide details</Question>
         <Answer>N/A</Answer>
         <Details>The pasta was too salty</Details>
     </questions>
 </Survey>
```

and Here is the piece of my code: (sorry, it is actually someoneelse's code.  I need to modify the part that display the next question when the previous one is specifically answered "Yes" or "No"

```
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
    <xsl:for-each select="../Survey">
        <xsl:for-each select="questions">
        <xsl:sort select="Number" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <fo:table-row>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="ends-with(Number,'0')">
                        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
                       <fo:block text-align="right">
                                <xsl:for-each select="Number"> ...
                           </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                <xsl:for-each select="Description"> ...
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center"> 
                            <fo:block text-align="left" color="blue">
                               <xsl:for-each select="Answer"> ...
                               </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>                                   </xsl:when>  
                    <xsl:when test="Number='1.1'">
                        <xsl:if test="//questions/Number='1.0' and //questions/Answer='No'">
                           <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
                               <fo:block text-align="right">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="Number"> ...
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                               </fo:block>
                           </fo:table-cell>
                           <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
                               <fo:block text-align="left">
                                   <xsl:for-each select="Question">  .....
                                   </xsl:for-each>
                               </fo:block>
                           </fo:table-cell>
                           <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center"> 
                              <fo:block text-align="left" color="blue">  ....
                                   <xsl:for-each select="Details">
                                   </xsl:for-each>
                              </fo:block>
                           </fo:table-cell>                                      </xsl:if>  
                       </xsl:when>  
                       <xsl:otherwise>do something</xsl:otherwise>                        </xsl:choose>
               </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
```

Comment: Are multiple answers allowed to be supplied in the same field in your XML? I noticed you had some that said "Yes/No" and "Yes|No".

Comment: Please give example of desired output. That will disambiguate the requirements. Also, your "What I need" paragraph will be less confusing if you put a period between sentences.

Comment: It would also help if you show one of the ways you tried, and then describe in what way it didn't work (what actually happened and how it differed from what you wanted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb. If your code contains a lot of duplication, you're doing it wrong. XSLT is no exception.

```
<!-- index followup questions (no zero after the dot) -->
<xsl:key 
  name="kFollowupQuestions"
  match="questions[number(substring-after(Number, '.')) != 0]" 
  use="number(substring-before(Number, '.'))"
/>

<!-- the <Survey> becomes the <fo:table-body> -->
<xsl:template match="Survey">
  <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
    <!-- only select main questions (with a zero after the dot) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="questions[number(substring-after(Number, '.')) = 0]">
      <xsl:sort select="Number" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </fo:table-body>
</xsl:template>

<!-- each <questions> becomes a <fo:table-row> -->
<xsl:template match="questions">
  <xsl:variable name="qNum"   select="number(substring-before(Number, '.'))" />
  <xsl:variable name="subNum" select="number(substring-after(Number, '.'))" />
  <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Number" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Question" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Answer" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Details" />
  </fo:table-row>
  <!-- for main question answered with 'Yes', display followup-questions --> 
  <xsl:if test="Answer = 'Yes' and $subNum = 0">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kFollowupQuestions', $qNum)">
      <xsl:sort select="Number" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- the <questions> children become <fo:table-cell>s -->
<xsl:template match="questions/*">
  <fo:table-cell border="solid 1pt gray" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
    <fo:block text-align="right">
      <xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- or whatever -->
    </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

http://www.xmlplayground.com/K4VHM2

Comment: +1 for use of key(), and for DRY principle. Note though that the correllation between Answer='Yes' and displaying the followup questions varies with the question. Sometimes followup is displayed only for Answer='No'. I think that's part of the reason for duplication. Though certainly some can be reduced.

Comment: @LarsH Then the input XML should contain an information what answer triggers the follow-up. Making this decision based on magic numbers (the question number) is a rather stupid idea. In any case, the `<xsl:if>` could be easily augmented like `test="$subNum = 0 and (($qNum = 1 and Answer = 'Yes') or ($qNum = 2 and Answer = 'No'))"` but that makes my brain hurt.

Comment: Stupid idea? It's not the ideal situation, but sometimes requirements are not what you'd like them to be. Maybe the OP has control over the contents of the input XML, maybe not.

Comment: @LarsH That's true. The idea won't get any smarter even when he's not in control, though. ;) I know sometimes things sometimes can't be helped and it was not meant as an insult to begin with.

Comment: Thank you so very much, Tomalak.  <br/>I agreed with you in all: that I should not hard-code the *.1 questions one by one  <br/>I am learning your way of coding using the template. This is the best example that I can easily understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I would change your

```
<xsl:when test="Number='1.1'">
   <xsl:if test="//questions/Number='1.0' and //questions/Answer='No'">
```

to

```
<xsl:when test="Number='1.1'">
   <xsl:if test="../questions[Number = '1.0']/Answer = 'No'">
```

That's assuming that you have no general way to know, for any question, whether you should display more details on a Yes answer or on a No answer, so you have a separate `<xsl:when>` case for each *.0 question.

P.S. It's odd that the XSL uses `<xsl:for-each select="Number">` etc. inside each `<fo:block>` since there is only one `<Number>` child of `<questions>` in your sample input. All that does is change the context node. Maybe the intent is to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="Number" />`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your advise and it worked fantastically. Thank you so very much for your help. Honestly, I am new to XSLT. And programming with surveys is always hectic.  The logic for a survey report is always like this: For each question ends with 0, display answer. For each question ends with 1 if the answer of 1.0 is Yes, display Details in 1.1 Details 1 -> Explanation 1 (could be multi-selection from a check-box.) Details 2 -> Explanation 2 if the answer of 2.0 is No, display Details in 2.1 Thank you all for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: @TuBiLe: You're welcome. Tomalak is right: rather than having a separate condition for each question, it would be better to encode in the input XML whether the details should be displayed on 'Yes' or on 'No'. Then your XSLT could be simple and consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The problem is I had no control over the XML.  This is a vendor application that my company bought.  My job is to customize the report while I had no access either to the code or the data: only this XSLT file that I have to make things work.

Comment: @TuBiLe: Understood. Sometimes the supplier of the XML doesn't have the same goals that you do (or doesn't care).